# ListPicker for WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, kiosk, listpicker

I'm developing a touch screen kiosk application in WPF. I'm leveraging the Microsoft Surface controls to make the application more touchscreen friendly, but I have yet to find a good replacement for the ComboBox - which seems to be one of the only options to pick a single value from a list, while using little screen real estate.

The Windows Phone 7 toolkit, in Silverlight, has a ListPicker, which is more or less exactly what I'm looking for, but as I understand it, since it's in Silverlight, I can't use it in my WPF app.

Before I try to build one from scratch, does anyone know of a ListPicker type control for WPF?

Barring that, anyone have any preferred alternatives to the standard ComboBox for a touchscreen application in WPF?

EDIT: To clarify, I know that WPF has a ComboBox, but this is not an ideal control for touch screen use. If you look at most phone or kiosk applications, ComboBox controls are avoided where possible. This is why I brought up the ListPicker (see here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/11/03/listpicker-i-hardly-even-know-er-a-detailed-overview-of-the-windows-phone-toolkit-s-listpicker-control.aspx), because it is a more touch-friendly control for this situation.

Comment: "I have yet to find a good replacement for the ComboBox" Huh? WPF has a ComboBox. Why do you need to find a replacement?

Comment: ComboBox is not an ideal control for touch screen use, which is why the ListPicker was developed. A ComboBox (as a drop down list) on a touch screen) is a rather clumsy control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try styling ListBox?

I think all you need to do is to remove the ScrollViewer (that can be done by using a custom ControlTemplate).

[Here is a quick tutorial how to do that](http://wpftutorial.net/templates.html).

[Here you can find the default template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278062%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) which you need to modify. Don't get scared by its size - the modifications should be quite simple.

Comment: Thanks - this is what I ended up doing and it works perfectly. Just had to use some code-behind for the transitions.